# funf scheduling and data collection

Tags: android, scheduled-tasks, android-sensors

I am new to Android programming and new to funf sensor framework. Based on the example give below is my take on scheduling the probe at specified intervals. But the sqlite database created is empty and i dont think the data is collected at all. any ideas please.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "APP";
    protected static final String PIPELINE_NAME = "default_pipeline";
    private FunfManager manager;
    private Pipeline pipeline;
    private Handler handler;

    private ServiceConnection conn = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            Log.e(TAG,"onServiceDisconnected");
            manager = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            Log.e(TAG,"onServiceConnected");
            manager = ((FunfManager.LocalBinder)service).getManager();
            pipeline = (BasicPipeline) manager.getRegisteredPipeline(PIPELINE_NAME);
            JsonObject jsonobject = (new JsonParser()).parse(getString(R.string.default_pipeline)).getAsJsonObject();
            if (pipeline == null){
                Log.e(TAG,"pipeling is null");
                manager.enablePipeline(PIPELINE_NAME);
                boolean flag = manager.saveAndReload(PIPELINE_NAME, jsonobject);
                Log.e(TAG,String.valueOf(flag));
                if (flag){
                    pipeline = manager.getRegisteredPipeline(PIPELINE_NAME);
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            Log.e(TAG,"will archive now");
                            pipeline.onRun("archive",null);
                        }
                    }, 10000L);
                }

            }
            else {
                Log.e(TAG,"pipeling is NOT null");
            }

        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.e(TAG,"onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        handler = new Handler();
        bindService(new Intent(this, FunfManager.class), conn, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        waitForServiceConnection(3000);
    }

    @Override
      protected void onDestroy() {
        Log.e(TAG,"onDestroy");
        super.onDestroy();
        unbindService(conn);
      }

    public void waitForServiceConnection(long millisToWait) {
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while (System.currentTimeMillis() < time + millisToWait) {
            if (manager != null) {
                break;
            } else {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

my strings.xml has the below value specified

```
    <string name="default_pipeline">{
                "name": "example",
                "version":1,
                "archive": {
                        "@schedule": {"interval": 60}
                },
                "upload": {
                        "url": \"http://www.samplewebsite.com/uploadurl\",
                        "@schedule": {"interval": 60}
                },
                "update": {
                        "url": \"http://www.samplewebsite.com/funfconfig\",
                        "@schedule": {"interval": 60}
                },
                "data": [
            {"@type": "edu.mit.media.funf.probe.builtin.LocationProbe",
                         "@schedule": {"interval": 5}
                        }
                ]
        }</string>
```

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: Based on the comment updated the onServiceConnected as below, but still i dont see database files created. I have completely uninstalled and reinstalled app restarted phone.

```
  private ServiceConnection conn = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            Log.e(TAG,"onServiceDisconnected");
            manager = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            Log.e(TAG,"onServiceConnected");
            manager = ((FunfManager.LocalBinder)service).getManager();
            pipeline = (BasicPipeline) manager.getRegisteredPipeline(PIPELINE_NAME);
            JsonObject jsonobject = (new JsonParser()).parse(getString(R.string.default_pipeline)).getAsJsonObject();
            if (pipeline == null){
                Log.e(TAG,"pipeline is null");
                pipeline = (BasicPipeline) manager.getRegisteredPipeline(PIPELINE_NAME);
                manager.saveAndReload(PIPELINE_NAME, jsonobject);
                manager.enablePipeline(PIPELINE_NAME);
            }
            else {
                Log.e(TAG,"pipeline is NOT null");
                Log.e(TAG,"Pipeline enabled? "+String.valueOf(pipeline.isEnabled()));
            }
            if (pipeline != null && !pipeline.isEnabled()){
                Log.e(TAG,"pipeline is not null and is NOT enabled");
                manager.enablePipeline(PIPELINE_NAME);
            }

        }
    };
```

Comment: Try to enable the pipeline AFTER you call `saveAndReload`. Other than that, the data will be written to database-files everytime you're archiving. Currently that's every 60 seconds, so I guess you don't really need manual archiving 10 seconds after your pipeline is saved for the first time.

Comment: Also, maybe you'll need to un- and reinstall your app afterwards, or enable the pipeline in your `onServiceConnected` if it is not null and also not yet enabled: `if (pipeline != null && !pipeline.isEnabled()) manager.enablePipeline(PIPELINE_NAME);`.

Comment: @Blacklight updated code, uninstalled and restarted phone, but still no luck.

Comment: Looks fine now (except you forgot to re-assign the pipeline to your variable after saving it for the first time: `pipeline = (BasicPipeline) manager.getRegisteredPipeline(PIPELINE_NAME);`). I still found something else, see my answer.

Comment: @Blacklight appreciate your help on this, is the updated serviceconnection look ok? i have changed PIPELINE_NAME too (thanks for pointing this out). Still don't see any database created. uninstalled,rebooted phone waited for 5 min achieve should be created every 1 min( 60 sec) according to config.

Comment: I edited my answer, looks almost ok now. If it still doesn't work I'm out of ideas, I'm basically doing the same in my code and the framework works. You could still debug your json-config and see if it is parsed correctly from your resources. Also pay attention to the framework-version, AFAIK the scheduling changed quite a bit with Funf 0.5 (I'm using 0.4.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of your pipeline is not "default_pipeline", that's just your resource name. It's "example" according to your config, so try this:

```
protected static final String PIPELINE_NAME = "example";
```

Other than that your config looks basically fine. A little optimization is still possible:

```
private ServiceConnection conn = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        Log.i(TAG,"onServiceDisconnected");
        manager = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        Log.i(TAG,"onServiceConnected");
        manager = ((FunfManager.LocalBinder)service).getManager();
        pipeline = (BasicPipeline) manager.getRegisteredPipeline(PIPELINE_NAME);
        if (pipeline == null){
            Log.i(TAG,"pipeline is null");
            JsonObject jsonobject = (new JsonParser()).parse(getString(R.string.default_pipeline)).getAsJsonObject();
            manager.saveAndReload(PIPELINE_NAME, jsonobject);
            manager.enablePipeline(PIPELINE_NAME);
            pipeline = (BasicPipeline) manager.getRegisteredPipeline(PIPELINE_NAME);
        }

        if (pipeline != null && !pipeline.isEnabled()){
            Log.e(TAG,"pipeline is not null and is NOT enabled");
            manager.enablePipeline(PIPELINE_NAME);
        }
    }
};
```

You could also try to simplify your configuration a bit to narrow it down:

```
{
    "name": "example",
    "version":1,
    "archive": {
        "@schedule": {"interval": 60}
    },
    "data": [
        {"@type": "edu.mit.media.funf.probe.builtin.LocationProbe",
         "@schedule": {"interval": 5}
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks. i was trying to use 0.5, but changed it to 0.4.2 and works great. One quick question, do the db files get deleted after they are uploaded?

Comment: Great. The DB files are by default not deleted after they are uploaded, however they will be moved from the archive to the backup folder.

Comment: appreciate if you can have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26841717/funf-delete-archive-files-after-upload