# funf delete archive files after upload

Tags: android, scheduled-tasks

I was able to get v0.4.2 funf version working to schedule and upload files. After the files are upload data is backed up  into "backup" folder. Does funf offer any options to limit the number of files to be backup/ delete old files etc?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour of the `DefaultArchive` (which I assume you are using) is explained [here](https://code.google.com/p/funf-open-sensing-framework/wiki/StoringData) as follows:

> The backup folder is occasionally cleaned up to delete older files.
>   Backup files are kept as long as they are not infringing on the free
>   space of the disk. The default archive will keep a minimum of 10MB of
>   backup, and a maximum equal to 50% of the free space available on the
>   drive. For instance if there is 200MB of free space available on the
>   SD Card, then the archive will store a backup of up to 100MB.

Of course, you can always modify this according to your needs by implementing your own archive.

Alternatively, you could e.g. schedule a repeating task using the [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html), in which you could clean up the backup-folder periodically using standard Java file-operations (there's a `#getPathOnSDCard()`-method in the DefaultArchive-object). Another possibility is to do this once manually after e.g. tapping a "delete backup"-button.